# Run crontab very 14th working day of month at 10h

Tags: linux, shell

please i want to create crontab that should runs evry 14th working day at 10am.

Im tried this row but still not giving what i want.

0 10 14 * 1-5
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

This will make it run on the 14th of the month (if that day falls between monday and friday)

0 10 */14 * 1-5

If you want it to run every 14 working days, you might want the cron job to call a script. Tell cron to run every day at 10. The script can then keep track of last time it ran, compare it and run if it's been 14 days and if today is a weekday.

Comment: thank you for your response ! Didn't got you about the script that I have to develop. Could you please help me more ?

Comment: I want to run the script on the 14th day of each month except weekends and holidays